# Passing a sqlcommand as a parameter. Throws invalid object error even if the object exist in the database

Tags: c#, sqlcommand

I have a problem with the following code. Please help.

What I am trying to do is pass a sqlcommand to a function which then returns a dataset.

**The function 'Get data' takes sqlcommand as a parameter. This function is in class 'DatabaseUtilities'**

```
    //Initializing sql connection
    static SqlConnection _Connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=db_Test;Integrated Security=True");

    //Connection property
    public static SqlConnection Connection
    {
        get {return _Connection;}
    }

    //The class that takes sqlcommand as parameter
    public static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand Command)
    {
        _Connection.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        Adapter.SelectCommand = Command;

        DataSet Table = new DataSet();

        Adapter.Fill(Table);

        _Connection.Close();

        return Table;
    }
```

**This is how sqlcommand is passed into the above function. This function is from a different class.**

```
public DataSet GetLogByDate(string SearchValue)
    {
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Command.Connection = DatabaseUtilities.Connection;

        Command.CommandText = "sp_GetLogByDate";
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogDate", SearchValue);

        return GetData(Command);
    }
```

**This code throws the fllowing error.**

Invalid object name 'sp_GetLogByDate'.

I do have the above stored procedure in my database. I have no idea why this happened. Could anyone help?

Comment: `static SqlConnection`is not a good idea when you use multiple threads (e.g. ASP.NET) and even Connection-Pooling is enabled (default):

Answer (score 2):

You have to connect `Command` with `Connection`:

```
//The class that takes sqlcommand as parameter
public static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand Command)
{
    Command.Connection = _Connection;
```

Comment: I did that in the class that passes the sqlcommand.              public DataSet GetLogByDate(string SearchValue)
    {
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Command.Connection = DatabaseUtilities.Connection;

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Command.Connection = DatabaseUtilities.Connection is not the same as the instance _Connection which is the one you opened.